# multiple MAP function in pyspark

Tags: mapreduce, pyspark, dbscan

Hi

I'm new in pyspark and i'm going to implement DBSCAN using MAP_REDUCE technique which is explained in https://github.com/mraad/dbscan-spark, but i don't understand something ,
obviously if we have multiple computers then we assign each cell to a MAP and as explained in the link, after calling REDUCE we find out Contents of each epsilon neighbor of cell, but in single computer how we can run and assign  MAP's to  cell's .
how do we define multiple maps in single computer(pyspark) and assign them too cell's ?

I wrote `fishnet(cell,eps)` that return point location according to cell's epsilon neighbor .
I want to pass it to each MAP but i don't know how to do it in pyspark.

Something like(if we have 4 cell's) :
`map1(fishnet)` `map2(fishnet)` `map3(fishnet)` `map4(fishnet)`

I would appriciate for any solution

Answer (score 0):

It's the job of Spark / MapReduce to distribute the mappers to different workers. Don't mess with that part, let Spark decide where to invoke the actual mappers.

Beware that Spark is not very well suited for clustering. It's clustering capabilities are very limited, and the performance is pretty bad. See e.g.:

> Neukirchen, Helmut. "Performance of Big Data versus High-Performance Computing: Some Observations."

It needed 900 cores with Spark to outperform a good single-core application like ELKI! And other Spark DBSCAN implementations would either not work reliably (i.e. fail) or produce wrong results.